# Google indexes my sitemap as webpage

Tags: indexing, robots.txt, google-crawlers, xml-sitemap

I have the following problem. My sitemap's content is shown in GOOGLE search results. There is a link to the sitemap on the main page. That can cause it. I have added this URL to GOOGLE as sitemap and I would like it to be treated as sitemap only, not as sitemap and webpage. How do I tell GOOGLE not to index it as webpage? Using robots.txt?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that your sitemap is Xml and conforms to the http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd schema?

Comment: I am almost sure. Google indexes URLs from this sitemap correctly and tells that it's correct sitemap file (using Webmasters Tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that google is indexing everything where they find links to.
You can prevent them with robots.txt as you stated.

[robots.txt](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_Exclusion_Standard)

Personally I have nerver seen something like that...
If you link to your website somewhere and tell us which URL you added to GOOGLE as sitemap I could take a look at it and see if it has something to do withthe way your site is built.

Hope this helps :-) tell me if you need any more info